# Xamarin forms: How to implement image cropping after selecting a picture from gallery or camera

Tags: xamarin.forms, camera, gallery

I am using [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) for opening Camera and Gallery to select pictures. After selecting a picture, I need to crop it before setting it on the UI. I have tried `AllowCropping = true` in the camera, but it works only for windows and ios. For the camera in android and gallery on all platforms (android, ios, and windows) there is no crop option.

I tried [ImageCropper.Forms](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms) package to implement the image cropping feature.

My Code:

```
//Camera
async void CameraClick()
{
    try
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            if (!Utility.IsWindowsDevice())
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No camera available.", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                ShowAlert("No camera available.");
            }
            return;
        }

        _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Sample",
            Name = "test.jpg",
            AllowCropping = true,
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
        });

        if (_mediaFile == null)
            return;
        profilephoto.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            isPicture = true;
            isAvatar = false;
            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
            {
                return _mediaFile.GetStreamWithImageRotatedForExternalStorage();
            }
            else
            {
                return _mediaFile.GetStream();
            }
        });

        new ImageCropper()
        {
            PageTitle = "Test Title",
            AspectRatioX = 1,
            AspectRatioY = 1,
            CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
            SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",
            TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",
            PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library",
            Success = (imageFile) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    profilephoto.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                });
            }
        }.Show(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
    }
}

//Gallery
async void GalleryClick()
{
    try
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
            if (!Utility.IsWindowsDevice())
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No photos available.", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                ShowAlert("No photos available.");
            }
            return;
        }

        _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
        {
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
        });

        if (_mediaFile == null)
            return;
        profilephoto.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            isPicture = true;
            isAvatar = false;
            return _mediaFile.GetStream();
        });

        new ImageCropper()
        {
            PageTitle = "Test Title",
            AspectRatioX = 1,
            AspectRatioY = 1,
            CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
            SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",
            TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",
            PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library",
            Success = (imageFile) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    profilephoto.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                });
            }
        }.Show(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
    }
}
```

I have done everything as per the blog, But when I run getting the below exception.

> [0:] Exception:>System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile> Plugin.Media.Abstractions.IMedia.TakePhotoAsync(Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:84
> at Stormlion.ImageCropper.ImageCropper.Show (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.String imageFile) [0x00033] in <548dc893a11b47fe908c9c3d7f4a39ba>:0
> at ProjectName.Pages.ProfilePage.GalleryClick () [0x00227] in F:\My Projects\Xamarin\ProjectName\ProjectName\ProjectName\Pages\ProfilePage.xaml.cs:554

> [0:] Exception:>System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile> Plugin.Media.Abstractions.IMedia.TakePhotoAsync(Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:84
> at Stormlion.ImageCropper.ImageCropper.Show (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.String imageFile) [0x00033] in <548dc893a11b47fe908c9c3d7f4a39ba>:0
> at ProjectName.Pages.ProfilePage.CameraClick () [0x0025b] in F:\My Projects\Xamarin\ProjectName\ProjectName\ProjectName\Pages\ProfilePage.xaml.cs:515
> 01-20 12:21:23.149 D/Mono    (11820): Requesting loading reference 1 (of 3) of System.Collections.dll

**Don't know what is the issue behind this. Is there any other simple package for implementing the image cropping feature?**

Comment: Does it work without using the package ImageCropper.Forms  ?

Comment: You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I will prepare the sample and share it with you ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Add **ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v2** nuget package to your project.

Then, if you use `AndroidX`, please change the code in  tag of AndroidManifest.xaml

```
<application android:label="ImageCropDemo.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
              android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
          android:exported="false"
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                       android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
    </application>
```

In addition, You do not need to call CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync, just execute ImageCropper directly like following code.

```
namespace ImageCropDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private MediaFile _mediaFile;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

 

            CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

 

        }
        protected  void OnClickedRectangle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new ImageCropper()
            {
                //                PageTitle = "Test Title",
                //                AspectRatioX = 1,
                //                AspectRatioY = 1,
                Success = (imageFile) =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    });
                }
            }.Show(this);
        }
        async void OpenCamera(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

 

                //if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                //{
                //    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No camera available.", "Ok");
                //    return;
                //}

 

                //_mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                //{
                //    Directory = "Sample",
                //    Name = "test.jpg",
                //    AllowCropping = true,
                //    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
                //});

 

                //if (_mediaFile == null)
                //    return;
                //image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                //{
                //    if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
                //    {
                //        return _mediaFile.GetStreamWithImageRotatedForExternalStorage();
                //    }
                //    else
                //    {
                //        return _mediaFile.GetStream();
                //    }
                //});

 

                new ImageCropper()
                {
                    PageTitle = "Test Title",
                    AspectRatioX = 1,
                    AspectRatioY = 1,
                    CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
                    SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",
                    TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",
                    PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library",
                    Success = (imageFile) =>
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                        });
                    }
                }.Show(this);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CameraException:>" + ex);
            }
        }
        string imagefile;
        async void OpenGallery(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

 

                //if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
                //{
                //    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No photos available.", "Ok");
                //    return;
                //}

 

                //_mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
                //{
                //    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
                //});

 

                //if (_mediaFile == null)
                //    return;

 

                //image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                //{
                //    return _mediaFile.GetStream();
                //});

 

                new ImageCropper()
                {
                    PageTitle = "Test Title",
                    AspectRatioX = 1,
                    AspectRatioY = 1,
                    CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
                    SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",
                    TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",
                    PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library",
                    Success = (imageFile) =>
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() =>
                        {
                            image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);

 

                            imagefile = imageFile;
                        });
                    }
                }.Show(this);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GalleryException:>" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the complete code in mainpage.xaml.cs?

Comment: Post it . When using the plugin ImageCropper , you don't need to use MediaPlugin any more because ImageCropper had contained it . But you still need to install and init the MediaPlugin .

Comment: OnClickedRectangle is a button click event .

Comment: Is it possible to set the final image value as a MediaFile? Because I need to post the selected image to our server like below: 'content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()), "\"file\"", $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");'

Comment: Currently I have used the _mediaFile.GetStream() and {_mediaFile.Path values.

Comment: var stream =  ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile); and upload it .

Comment: for the path? `mediaFile.Path`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227598/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: it is not working in ios. Is this solution only for the android part?

Comment: Sreejith Sree, @Lucas Zhang, do you guys might helping me out with similar issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463690/android-how-to-take-a-photo-and-crop-using-imagecropper-forms