# android - How to take a photo and crop using ImageCropper.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**ill take any help here..** I am using xamarin and would like to:

1. Click on button
2. Open Camera
3. Take photo
4. Crop Photo
5. Create Folder in Gallery
6. Save Cropped photo in new folder in Gallery

I am following tutorial - ***Ref:*** https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms

Currently, When I tap on button, Camera opens up, but it doesnt crops or saves photo. Since Camera opens up, that means my set up and perrmission are correct.

Why this code isnt working from github and how can I crop photo?  Please let me know what am I missing here.

after doing some debugging, following code is not getting runned. i this issue is with properties

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        ImageURL.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    });
```

**view back-end**

```
    public partial class AddCardPage : ContentPage
    {
        public AddCardPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        }

        protected async void TapGestureRecognizerCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();


                await new ImageCropper()
                {
                    PageTitle = "Test Title",
                    AspectRatioX = 1,
                    AspectRatioY = 1,
                    CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle, //Cropt shape
                    SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",
                    TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",
                    PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library",
                    Success = (imageFile) =>
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            ImageURL.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                        });
                    }
                }.Show(this);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CameraException:>" + ex);
            }
        }//end of method

    }//end of class
}
```

Other Info:
I downloaded 2 nugets: **ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v7** and **Xam.Media.Plugin**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you used is too old. You could use `ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v2` instead.

Add the code below in your MainActivity:

```
   Stormlion.ImageCropper.Droid.Platform.Init();
   protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Stormlion.ImageCropper.Droid.Platform.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Add the code in  tag of AndroidManifest.xaml:

```
<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity" android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
```

Code behind:

```
 new ImageCropper()
        {
            //                PageTitle = "Test Title",
            //                AspectRatioX = 1,
            //                AspectRatioY = 1,
            Success = (imageFile) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                });
            }
        }.Show(this);
```

When you click the button, it would pop up a window. If you want to take photo, choose the  `Take Photo`. Please note, you need to add the `CAMERA` permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

[image]

Or you could select the image from the device to crop.

[image]

**OutPut:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vfst.jpg

Comment: thanks! I was using v7... bc i though it was version 7 (lastest).. turn out v2 was the lastest version.. confousing naming

Comment: also i noticed a small bug... if user click on button on main page, camera opens up, than take photo and confirm, but than it goes back to main page... waits 2 secs than opens up crop. is there way to direclty open crop after taking photo?