# Is there any plugin or a way to capture images while video capturing is going on in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, video-capture

I have a requirement that, need to capture an image in midway while video recording is going on but video capturing should not be interrupted.

Is there any way to achieve this Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Just a guess. Can you try xamarin.essentials screenshot taker? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screenshot

Comment: Screenshot will contain full screen right including device status bar. But I need the image exactly like we click a photo using camera application

Comment: You could take the screenshot first and then crop the image via `ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v2`. The link below is used to crop the image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463690/android-how-to-take-a-photo-and-crop-using-imagecropper-forms/67467026#67467026